Postman Test Scripts
For my postman project,testscript template are same for most requests.I don't want to maintain it all requests.
I want to keep all test assertions inside like a method and need to call that method inside the requests wherever required.
Any solution for this
My Testscript template is

I am thinking the way...

Which way are you thinking? Please share all code in text form

I didn't fetch any solution...Planned to keep common template...I don't know will work or not...Searching

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Note that text should never be presented as an image.

Postman is using JavaScript for the testing.  I have created functions that I can re-use, to parse data, return values, etc.  While this is not necessarily the direct use you have, it could work.
In the collection, I put the functions I am going to call into the Pre-Request script, Variables also has anything I need set as well.
As these are functions, you can streamline the test by using common functions, or simply add the couple of lines in each test case.
For instance, in my pre-request script
SharedFunctions = {

    // configuration/1.35.0 - returns configuration
    GetServiceNameFromString: function (StringValue) {
        const ServiceName = StringValue.split('/');
        return ServiceName[0];
    },

    // configuration/1.35.0, 1, 32, 0
    IsVersionAtLeast: function (StringValue, Major, Minor, Patch) {
        const ServiceInfo = StringValue.split('/');
        const VersionInfo = ServiceInfo[1].split('.');
        if (parseInt(VersionInfo[0]) > Major) { return true; }
        if (parseInt(VersionInfo[0]) < Major) { return false; }

        // Major is equal if here
        if (parseInt(VersionInfo[1]) > Minor) { return true; }
        if (parseInt(VersionInfo[1]) < Minor) { return false; }

        // Major & Minor are equal if here
        if (parseInt(VersionInfo[2]) >= Patch) { return true; }
        return false;
    },

}

I then can reference these functions from any test by adding a test case in the normal test location
pm.test('SharedFunctions should work', function () {
    const SMEService = pm.response.headers.get('MyHeader-ServiceName');
    const ServiceName = SharedFunctions.GetServiceNameFromString(SMEService);
    pm.expect(ServiceName).not.null;
    pm.expect(ServiceName).to.equal('configuration');
    pm.expect(SharedFunctions.IsVersionAtLeast(SMEService, 1, 15, 0)).to.equal(true);
});

As the shared functions can accept parameters, you can make your call to the external service, and send the response as the first parameter.  Write your Shared function test to simply return true/false, and then your test simply has the call to the shared function returns true.
For instance:
CommonValidationFunction = {
   // Validate Job Added Successfully
   ValidateJobAdd: function (jsonData) {
      if (jsonData.Message != "JobAddedSuccessMessage") return false
      if (jsonData.ErrorCode != 0) return false
      ...
      return true;
   }
}

Your test then simply calls your external service to get the jsonData.
pm.test("Common Function works", function () {
   pm.expect(CommonValidationFunction.ValidateJobAdd(jsonData)).to.equal(true);
}


Glad it helped.  I think you could do more complex work, include the pm.expect in the functions, but I liked to keep mine more basic, so I could re-use them for more than just the tests.  For instance, break up the various evaluations, and then paste the block(s) needed.  You can also look at pre-request scripts on individual tests if needed, or folders even.
